# Regex find and copy in bash (preserving folder structure)?

Tags: bash, find

I have a folder with a bunch of log files. Each set of log files is in a folder detailing the time and date that the program was run. Inside these log folders, I've got some video files that I want to extract. All I want is the video files, nothing else. I tried using this command to only copy the video files, but it didn't work because a directory didn't exist.

.rmv is the file extension of the files I want.

```
$ find . -regex ".*\.rmv" -type f -exec cp '{}' /copy/to/here/'{}'
```

If I have a folder structure such as:

```
|--root  
   |  
   |--folder1  
   |  |  
   |  |--file.rmv  
   |  
   |--folder2  
      |  
      |--file2.rmv
```

How can I get it to copy to copy/to/here with it copying the structure of folder1 and folder2 in the destination directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Comment: This works if I use rsync and then run rmdir over the directory it gets copied to (since it creates folders that don't have anything in them). I used the command:

'  rsync -rv root copy/to/here --exclude="*.log" --include="*.rmv"  '

The only other files inside the directories were .log files. For some reason, if I only specified include it would still copy all of the files.

Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan: Take a look at the `--prune-empty-dirs` and `--delete*` options to see if they help.

Answer (score 12):

cp has argument --parents
so the shortest way to do what you want is:

```
find root -name '*.rmv' -type f -exec cp --parents "{}" /copy/to/here \;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` represents the full path of the found file, so your `cp` command evaluate to this sort of thing:

```
cp /root/folder1/file.rmv /copy/to/here/root/folder1/file.rmv
```

If you just drop the second `{}` it will instead be

```
cp /root/folder1/file.rmv /copy/to/here
```

the copy-file-to-directory form of cp, which should do the trick.

Also, instead of `-regex`, yor could just use the `-name` operand:

```
find root -name '*.rmv' -type f -exec cp {} /copy/to/here \;
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't preserve the folder structure. Inside of the folders, some of the files are named the same. So I don't get all of the files because some keep getting overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `src` is your `root` and `dst` is your `/copy/to/here`

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name *.rmv | while read f
do
       path=$(dirname "$f" | sed -re 's/src(\/)?/dst\1/')
       echo "$f -> $path"
       mkdir -p "$path"
       cp "$f" "$path"
done
```

putting this in `cp.sh` and running `./cp.sh` from the directory over root

Output:

```
./src/folder1/file.rmv -> ./dst/folder1
./src/My File.rmv -> ./dst
./src/folder2/file2.rmv -> ./dst/folder2
```

EDIT: improved script version (thanks for the comment)

Comment: This won't work if there are spaces in the names. Use `find ... | while read f ...` instead. Also, you should quote filename variables: `"$f"` and `"$path"` for the same reason. Use this: `echo "$f -> $path"` - it's more readable. If your shell supports it (most do), use `$()` instead of [backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). None of those semicolons are necessary, by the way.